# What is new in Ducktales Remastered?

Tags: ducktales-remastered

Ducktales on the NES is by far one of the best license video games of all time, and was recently (relatively) made into a Remastered version, "Ducktales Remastered".

And yet...by the look of a few preview videos I've seen, much of the game is basically the same.  Same levels, same layout, a bit of shiny polish and remixing of music, maybe a few revamped bosses but not much else.

So what *has* been added to the new Remastered version of Ducktales?

Note that I am not asking for feature changes, because obviously they've polished the game quite a lot.  I'm asking about straight-up additions to the game. I noticed there's a music track for "Mount Vesuvious" on youtube, which I assume is a brand new level.  Are there other new levels?  And is it an entirely new level, or just a reskin of Transylvania the way they re-used Transylvania in the original game 3 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two news levels.

The vault at the very beginning. This is kind of a tutorial level.

then there is Mount Vesuvious at the very end.

Both are completely new levels but are also very linear.

Several of the carry over levels are significantly expanded from their 8-bit versions with additional areas and alternate routes.

Other new additions:

You can swim in the money pit.

There is a gallery in which you can unlock pictures and music from both the new and original game.

You can save your progress between levels.

Animated cut scenes voiced by the original cast.

Think of it as more of a "remix" thank a remake.